# Как сделать условия для conctact form?

Tags: wordpress, contact-form7

Как сделать так в контакт форме 7,что бы при выборе определенного города выбирался и отдельный е-мейл и отправлялся только одному человеку в зависимости от города.

```
<label>Место жительства:[select sel-12
"gamburg"
"newyork" 
"tokio" 
 ]</label>
```

**Например**

- gamburg - 1@mail.com
- newyork - 2@mail.com
- tokio - 3@mail.com

Answer (score 1, accepted):

в cf7 есть специальный функционал для этого. Вам нужно изменить шорткод выпадающего списка так что бы каждая опция имела следующую структуру `"название|значение"` в вашем случае это будет вот так:

```
<label>Место жительства:[select sel-12
"gamburg|1@mail.com"
"newyork|2@mail.com" 
"tokio|3@mail.com" 
 ]</label>
```

после это вам нужно отредактировать шаблон письма, вставьте шорткод выпадающего списка в поле получателей сообщения `[sel-12]`. Если вам так же нужно отправлять это значение в теле письма то вы можете это сделать следующим шорткодом `[_raw_sel-12]`.

[подробнее по ссылке](https://contactform7.com/selectable-recipient-with-pipes/)